# Nodes anchors in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, foreach, loops, for-loop

I need to change the anchor of a node depending on the sign. For example, if the sign is "-", then the anchor is "north", otherwise "south". To do this, I implemented the function using `\def`:

```
    \def\side#1{%
        \ifnum#1=-1%
        north%
        \else%
        south%
        \fi%
    }
```

The solution is working, but inconsistent. Can I somehow implement this by `TikZ`? The question is probably even global. How can you define a function that returns not a numeric value, but, for example, an anchor?
Maybe there is an even better/compact solution.

An MWE below

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[draw] (A) at (-1,0) {};
    \node[draw] (B) at (1,0) {};
    
    \def\side#1{%
        \ifnum#1=-1%
        north%
        \else%
        south%
        \fi%
    }
    
    \foreach [evaluate=\i as \j using int(-1*\i)] \i in {-1, 1}
    {
        \draw[->] (A.\side{\i}) -- (B.\side{\j}) ; 
    } 
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `tikzpicture` is yours, the second one seems to be purely TikZ-based:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[draw] (A) at (-1,0) {};
    \node[draw] (B) at (1,0) {};
    
    \def\side#1{%
        \ifnum#1=-1%
        north%
        \else%
        south%
        \fi%
    }
    
    \foreach [evaluate=\i as \j using int(-1*\i)] \i in {-1, 1}
    {
        \draw[->] (A.\side{\i}) -- (B.\side{\j}) ; 
    } 
    
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[draw] (A) at (-1,0) {};
    \node[draw] (B) at (1,0) {};
    
    
    
    \foreach [evaluate=\i as \j using int(-1*\i)] \i in {90, 270}
    {
        \draw[->] (A.{\i}) -- (B.{\j}) ; 
    } 
    
\end{tikzpicture}

And the third

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[draw] (A) at (-1,0) {};
    \node[draw] (B) at (1,0) {};
    
    
    
    \foreach [evaluate=\i as \j using int(-1*\i)] \i in {-1, 1}
    {
        \draw[->] (A.{180+90*\i}) -- (B.{180+90*\j}) ; 
    }



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clever solution. But I would leave \i as -1 and 1, they can serve as a sign in other places. I get the idea. Thank you.

Comment: @sergiokapone So the third `tikzpicture` seems to be the desired version (no new picture added).